# Flash messages not working for Rails3 + Haml + RefineryCMS + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, refinerycms

I'm unable to use flash in my haml and erb views. I can however use session[:flash], except in one case: after an unsuccessful login with devise, I want to show flash[:alert] or even session[:flash][:alert], but neither work. Both return nil and my page explodes. I can see in the session dump that flash[:alert] is set by devise. Why in the world can't I access it? I'm using Rails3 + Haml + RefineryCMS + Devise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible RefineryCMS is already outputting the flash before you are trying to access it and therefore Rails is removing it?